# javascript how to remove all parents element in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

string like this:

```
var str = '<div><span>spm</span></div><p><div>hmm</div></p>';
```

after remove it would like this:

```
var str = '<span>spm</span><div>hmm</div>';
```

Comment: You could use dom manipulation to do this if you create a div, add the contents of the string to the div's html,then traverse it's tree to find the leaf nodes, and then copy them to a string.

Comment: noooooo don't tag your question with `regex` =( browser devs and jquery work so hard giving you the right selectors/tools.

Comment: You would be able to work with DOM manipulation if your markup wasn't invalid. `<div>` inside `<p>` ???

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you need regex something this:

```
var str = '<div><span>spm</span></div><p><div>hmm</div></p>';
var removed= str.match(/<(\w+)[^<>]*>[\s\w]*<\/\1>/ig).join('');
```

#### Note:

To remove all parents elements we need find all texts concluded in tags: <...>any text<...>. The simplest way is find sequences: open tag; text; close tag. In regex wrote above we find all this sequences and concatenate its together. To find in whole string and ignore case-sensitive we use special regex flags "ig". It should be noticed that this solution works for common texts in tags contains only alphanumeric characters, "_" and dividers (space, tab and etc).

Comment: Regardless of whether regex is the right means here, this is a neat idea! :)